# Does multiplication operator have eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the infinite dimensional space of all complex polynomials $p(z)$ does the operator $O$ representing multiplication by $x$ have any eigenvectors?

Since the multiplication operator is $O[p(z)]=xp(z),$ doesn't this show that $x$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $p(z)$?

Comment: If the polynomial is $p(z)$, then it is unclear what "multiplication by $x$" even means.

Comment: This is my favourite example to explain why looking for eigenvectors in infinite dimensional vector spaces is hopeless (without additional assumptions). Eigenvalues need to be scalars, the polynomial $x$ is not.

Comment: Please clarify what $x$ is. If $x$ has to be $z$, please edit your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the scalar $\lambda$ were to be an eigenvalue of $O$ there would have to be a polynomial $p(z)$ such that 
$$
O(p(z)) = zp(z) = \lambda p(z)
$$
That can't happen because the degree of $zp(z)$ is greater that the degree of $p(z)$.

The question is a little confusing. I read "$x$" as "$z$". If $x$ is just a number then the operator "multiplication by $x$" is just the operator $xI$ and every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $x$.

Comment: I think OP means $x$ is a number. Not sure though.

Comment: @Mark Perhaps. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean $x$ is just a number. If this is the case then yes, look at the map $O-\lambda I$. It is defined by $(O-\lambda I)(p)=O(p)-\lambda p=xp-\lambda p=(x-\lambda)p$. And it is obvious its kernel is non-trivial iff $\lambda=x$. So this is the only eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simple scaling operators are the ultimate in degeneracy: every vector is an eigenvalue with the same eigenvalue. That eigenvalue has an algebraic and geometric multiplicity equal to the dimension of the space; in this case, that is $\omega$. We can choose any basis for the space, and the operator will be diagonal in that basis.